# PHP implode quoted string

Tags: php, implode

```
$brand_condition = ' AND ' . mysql_real_escape_string($brand_selection) . ' IN ';

$brand_condition .= $quote10 . '"'. mysql_real_escape_string($brand_value) . '"' .$quote9;

$brand_conditions[] = $brand_condition;

$query .= implode(' AND ', $brand_conditions) . '';
```

This produces: AND manufacturer IN ("brand1,brand2")

Since I'm using the IN statement, I need the values to be quoted. At the same time, I am escaping potential quotes with mysql_real_escape_string.

Does anyone see a simple way to get around this small problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function quote_escape(&$str) {
    $str = '"' . mysql_real_escape_string(chop($str)) . '"';
}

$brands = explode(',', $brand_value);
array_walk($brands, "quote_escape");
$brands = implode(',', $brands);
```

or

```
function quote_escape($str) {
     return '"' . mysql_real_escape_string(chop($str)) . '"';
}
$brands = implode(',', array_map("quote_escape", explode(',', $brand_value)));
```

Comment: change it from array_walk to array_map, remove the repeated assignments, and you have my upvote.

Comment: I'm not sure that's a readable solution for the OP, but as you wish :P

Comment: Where exactly is the AND statement supposed to be placed?

Comment: $query .= ('AND manufacturer IN'. '('. $brands).')'; --Nevermind

Answer (score 2):

How about `$brand_conditions[] = '"'.$brand_condition.'"';` so your adding quotes right before you add the brand_condition in your array.

Answer (score 1):

```
$concurrent_names = array("O'reilly", 'Tupac "MC New York" Shakur', 'Nemoden');
$escaped_concurrent_names = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $concurrent_names);
$condition = 'WHERE name in ("'.implode('", "', $escaped_concurrent_names).'")';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to add quotes for imploded string.

$values = implode( " ',' ", array_values($values) );

Answer (score -1):

```
$brands=array(nokia,samsung,xiomi);

$brands=implode(" ',' ",$brand);

//$brands='nokia','samsung','xiomi';

WHERE column_name IN ($brands)
```